# get array value for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, each

I have array

```
numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

I have a variable:

```
number = 4
```

I want with a loop for or each block return false unless the number 4 for this case exist in array.

```
numbers.each do |number_loop| 
    return false unless number_loop == number   
end
```

But I get an error:

**LocalJumpError: unexpected return
    from (irb):25:in `block in irb_binding'**

Comment: Is this code obfuscated for the purposes of posting here? Because there are far better ways to determine if an array contains a value.

Comment: What do you think you're returning from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing something else in the block that you've hidden from posting here, why don't you just do:

```
return false if numbers.include? number
```

As for the reason you get a `LocalJumpError` there: if your code isn't in a method then there isn't anything to return to (or, put another way: nothing to *jump* back to). In that case you're probably trying to set a variable rather than return, and you'd want to do:

```
is_included = numbers.include? number
```

Comment: Thank you it does works fine. This response its perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
 numbers.include?(number)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you should use `#include?` to check for inclusion. Also take a look at `#any?` and `#all?` which can be used to check whether any or all elements in a collection match a certain block.